# How to listen to Google Maps API events without an external library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I'm trying to understand how I would use React to respond to Google Maps JS API events without the react-google-maps library for my own knowledge. Would this be done in the traditional Javascript way of adding event listeners?

In particular, I'm trying to respond to a click event on a Google Maps Marker with a function defined in the same React component that the Google Map is created in.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I will explain you how to add an event listener to a map using js and next how to create an event with a custom event listener.

---

First, add an event listener in your map using js. The solution is very easy. You can use this line of code:

```
//Listen to your map
map.addListener('idle', function (e) {
   alert("Load");
});
```

Here, you add a simple listener to an object (in the example, the map). This code add an alert on your window when the map is fully load (idle).

You can consult google's event documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview).

---

Next, we try to create a custom listener and a custom event.

This line initialize an event 'build':

```
var event = new Event('build');
```

And this line call all listener of this event 'build':

```
// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Now, we can create a listener:

```
//Listen to your custom event
window.addEventListener('build', function () {
    console.log('OK');
});
```

My code looks like this:

```
var event = new Event('build');
//Listen to your custom event
window.addEventListener('build', function () {
    console.log('OK');
});
// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can have the complete documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).